# Can't show google maps android markers from coords stored in mysql db

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I can't fetch markers from coordinates stored in a mysql db. Where's the error in my codes?

P.S. LAT and LON fields in my table have VARCHAR type.

--MapsActivity.java

```
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Double Latitude = 0.00;
    private Double Longitude = 0.00;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> location = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String url = "http://192.168.1.101/crud/markers_android.php";
        try {

            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(url);
            location = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("LAT", c.getString("LAT"));
                map.put("LON", c.getString("LON"));
                location.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < location.size(); i++) {

            Latitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("LAT").toString());
            Longitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("LON").toString());
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude));
            mMap.addMarker(marker);
        }
    }


}
```

file php markers_android.php is [here](http://pastebin.com/HEKxBCRd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a log to see what response you get from json

```
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("LAT", c.getString("LAT"));
                map.put("LON", c.getString("LON"));
                Log.w("eeee", "Lat : " + c.getString("LAT") + "  Lon : " + c.getString("LON")); // add this line
                location.add(map);
            }
```

And give us the answer back if you can!